# Automapper como implementar de forma correcta

Tags: c#, automapper

Estoy usando automapper 7 pero la documentación de esta versión no es muy explicita  tengo implementado de esta manera.

1) Declaro a nivel de clase.

```
private MapperConfiguration _config;
```

2) Implemento de esta manera para mapear de una entidad a otra.

```
public void Creado(ProductoCatalogoExtend entity)
    {
        _config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ProductoCatalogoExtend, ProductoCatalogo>();
        });
        var mapper = _config.CreateMapper();
        var dto = mapper.Map<ProductoCatalogo>(entity);
        _sdProductoCatalogo.Create(dto);
    }
```

Me parece que esta implementación se puede mejorar, creo que se puede utilizar menos lineas de código.

No me parece muy buena la documentación de esta versión [Automapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Static-and-Instance-API.html) otras versiones tenían buena documentación en Github y habían mejores ejemplos.

Saludos!

> Nota: Es una app Windows Forms, no uso ningún patrón de diseño.

Comment: La pregunta es un poco amplia ya que el mapeo lo puedes aplicar para ViewModels en aplicaciones de escritorio, para WebApi, para Xamarin y pues depende del Application Model es como se podria implementar bien el mapeo.

Comment: @DanMiranda modifique mi pregunta, faltaban datos. La pregunta esta basada en la documentación de la misma, si alguien conoce una mejor implementación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera sencilla de poder utilizar el `AutoMapper` es crear una configuración estática que se cargue en el `Main` de `Program.cs` antes de `Application.Run`

Dejare un ejemplo mapeando una clase Persona a PersonaViewModel:

```
public class Persona
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
}

public class PersonaViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NombreCompleto { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }

}


static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        // configuracion estatica de automapper
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

AutoMapperConfiguration:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
        });
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

MappingProfile:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Persona, PersonaViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NombreCompleto, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.Nombre} { src.Apellido }"))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Edad, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => DateTime.Now.Year - src.FechaNacimiento.Year));
    }
}
```

El uso se resumiría en una sola linea de código:

```
var persona = new Persona
{
    Id = 78,
    Nombre = "Fulanito",
    Apellido = "De tal",
    FechaNacimiento = new DateTime(1985, 1, 1)
};

var personaViewModel = Mapper.Map<PersonaViewModel>(persona);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos, espero te sirva

Comment: En la clase `MappingProfile:`

Comment: No entendi tu duda, puedes extenderla?

Comment: Disculpa se me paso el tiempo de editarla, en esa clase en mención van todos los objetos que deseo mapear, así no ensucio la vista o formulario donde estoy trabajando.

Comment: Exacto, ya todos los mapping se declaran e implementan ahí y los cargas antes de levantar la aplicación.

Comment: Excelente aporte actualmente tengo implementado el automapper en la capa de servicios pero como no he hecho mucho lo implementare en presentación y usare la técnica que sugieres me gusta.

Comment: Otro detalle en mi implementación le paso la entidad a granel no lo especifico como tu lo haces en tu caso, ¿sería valido lo que hago? igual funciona.

Comment: Te refieres al MappingProfile?, si es asi, las propiedades que tengan el mismo nombre se mapean automaticamente, por eso en el ejemplo **Id** no lo mapeo pero si la Propiedad **NombreCompleto** por que esta compuesto de la unión de nombre y apellido de la otra entidad persona

Comment: Muchas gracias resolviste mis dudas.

Comment: Solo como información adicional ya que mencionaste servicios,  tambien  se puede usar muy similar al ejemplo y si es *Net core* mucho mas simple aun